# screen isn't scrolling up when the keyboard appers

Tags: java, android, xml, scroll, keyboard

screen isn't scrolling up when the keyboard appers. I've read many answers saying to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="something"` I tried many of them

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" 

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

(also tried some others) none of them worked

I think the problem is on my xml which the most was generated by android studio "activity login" template.

is there any other way to do it?

my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.eduardo.academia.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMudarSenha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:onClick="mudarSenha"
                android:clickable="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eduardo.academia">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExerciciosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exercicios"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you need use scrollView for scrolling

Comment: I could change the second LinearLayout to scrollView but didn't work anyway. When I changed first and third LinearLayout to scrollView genereted these exeptions respectively "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: ScrollView can host only one direct child" and  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b3db574 does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ScrollView` for this. try below xml for your layout

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.eduardo.academia.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMudarSenha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:onClick="mudarSenha"
                android:clickable="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: by the way, can I make the image ImageView disapper when the keyboard pops up?

Comment: Is scroll  not working?  you can hide  image when  keyboard popups.  Use ViewTreeObserver for this

Comment: It does scroll but doesn't scroll enough. The button is hidden by the keyboard. Take look on image on my previous comment

Comment: Add margin bottom for the last textView or Add View with transparent background and height 100dp or something at the bottom of layout